# Integrating a second-order partial derivative over a triangular region

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

A question from Chapter $14$ of Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis" ($2^{\text{nd}}$ edition):

> $\mathbf{14.15}$ Let $T$ denote the following triangular region in the plane: $$ T = \left\{ (x,y) \colon 0 \leq \frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} \leq 1 \right\}, \quad \text{where } a \gt 0, \, b \gt 0
> $$
> Assume that $f$ has a continuous second-order partial derivative $D_{1,2}f$ on $T$. Prove that there is a point $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ on the segment joining $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ such that $$
> \int_{T}D_{1,2}f(x,y) \,d(x,y) = f(0,0) - f(a,0) + aD_{1}f(x_{0}, y_{0}).
> $$

This seems to be an application of one of a mean-value theorem, but beyond that, I don't see how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Note that, in this context, $\int_{T}$ is a multiple Reimann integral over the region $T$. $D_{1,2}f$ denotes taking the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the second and first coordinates, in that order.